# Update chart title in Google Sheet with App Script without resetting other options

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a chart in a Google Sheets document with a title that I am trying to update using Apps Script as part of another command. I am using the modify().setOption().build() method.

Whenever I run this line, it correctly updates the title. However, it also resets the line colors to the default Google palette. Resetting the colors defeats a large part of the purpose of the chart, and I would rather have no title but correct colors.

Is there a way I can update the title of a chart in a sheet without resetting the line colors? Or is there no other way, so I would just have to extend the script to also update line colors after updating the title?

This is the line of code - I know it's not good form to do it in a single line, but the code works, and the color reset I cannot imagine is related to it:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Chart").updateChart(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Chart").getCharts()[0].modify().setOption('title', 'new title').build());
```

Thank you

Comment: I changed my chart to an area chart and was getting the same behavior.  I could not find any reason it is doing this, as it works on other chart types.   I removed my answer since it isn't helpful.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I had this issue a couple years ago, where it would reset colors. I just changed the script to reassign colors after the title change, and now it's functioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do that with `modify().setOption().build()` method.
The reason is that this method uses the [UpdateChartSpecrequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatechartspecrequest) which does not support position and object properties of the [EmbeddedChart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#EmbeddedChart) object.

You need to:

1. use Sheets API [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) to read the chart data, make a copy of the chart JSON object and alter the properties you want (the title in this case)
2. remove the existing sheet with [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate), [DeleteEmpbeddedObjectRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deleteembeddedobjectrequest)
3. finally, add a "new" chart using the JSON object from step 1 with [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate), [AddChartRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#AddChartRequest)

To run this function, you must add the `Google Sheets API service` to your script.

```
function renameChart(){
  const ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()
  const resp = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId, {"fields":"sheets(charts)"}) // read chart(s)
  const chart = resp.sheets[0].charts[0] // assume there is a single chart on the first sheet
  chart.spec.title='New Title'
  // request order is important, first delete existing and then add a new chart
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
    requests:[
    {
      deleteEmbeddedObject:{ objectId:chart.chartId }
    }, 
    {
      addChart:{ chart } }
    ]}, ssId )
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. I ended up just assigning the colors in the script, but I may need this in the future if there are other parts of it that can't be addressed that way

Answer (score 0):

I believe they must have changed the color editing since this post. The following code works and maintains my chart aesthetics:

```
//rewrite the text containing titles and axes for the main chart

function rewriteChartText() {
  
  //grab the current sheet and chart
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0]; //may need to change 0 if you add more charts

  //identify cells where text info is stored
  var titleCell = sheet.getRange("AO1");
  var subtitleCell = sheet.getRange("AO2");
  var xAxisCell = sheet.getRange("AO3");
  var yAxisCell = sheet.getRange("AO4");

  //grab values from those cells
  var title = titleCell.getValue();
  var subtitle = subtitleCell.getValue();
  var xAxis = xAxisCell.getValue();
  var yAxis = yAxisCell.getValue();

  //modify the chart
  var updatedChart = chart.modify()
    .setOption('title', title)
    .setOption('subtitle', subtitle)
    .setOption('hAxis.title', xAxis)
    .setOption('vAxis.title', yAxis)
    .build();

//  var updatedChart = chart.modify()
//    .setOption()


  //update the chart
  sheet.updateChart(updatedChart);
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?